# Speed up jQuery fadeOut on Cordova

Tags: jquery, cordova

I made an image fader/slider for a screensaver on a cordova application. Image sizes average 200KB - 400KB The HTML is below:

```
<div id="screensaver" class="screensaver">
  <img src="img/landing-bg_1.jpg" class="active" alt="alt" />
  <img src="img/landing-bg_2.jpg" alt="alt" />
  <img src="img/landing-bg_3.jpg" alt="alt" />
</div>
```

and jQuery:

```
function cycleImages(){

  var $active = $('#screensaver .active');
  var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $( '#screensaver img:first ');

  $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile

  $active.fadeToggle(500,function(){

    //fade out the top image
    $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
    $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one

  });

}
```

The problem that I am having is that it is scrolling smoothly on a browser, but as soon as I compile the app to the APK it slows down considerably and becomes jumpy. Is there any way to force this to use either hardware acceleration or something.

I have searched the site but couldn't find a similar issue. If I noobed out sorry about that I'm new to the site :)

Comment: Do u test it on a real Android Device or in a Simulator?

Comment: I tested the app on a Samsung Galaxy TAB 4 as well as a Samsung S5, both with the same sluggish result. When I test it on the Ripple emulator however it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Romain Durand. I took your suggestion to use CSS3 rather than jQuery and looked for a way to use the animate function rather than the fadeToggle(). This, according to my logic would call CSS functionality rather than the jQuery.

In conjunction with that I found an awesome plugin called jQuery Animate enhanced here: https://github.com/benbarnett/jQuery-Animate-Enhanced that helped me push the animate function even further.

Here follows the code that I used, which works great and smooths out the transition on my Android device:

JavaScript:

```
$('#screensaver > div:first')
.animate( { opacity: 0 }, 1000 )
.next()
.fadeIn( 1000 )
.end()
.appendTo( '#screensaver' );
```

HTML:

```
<div id="screensaver" class="screensaver">
    <div><img src="img/landing-bg_1.jpg" alt="alt text" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/landing-bg_2.jpg" alt="alt text" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/landing-bg_3.jpg" alt="alt text" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are looking for but I strongly recommend not to use jquery for animation in a mobile app.
This framework is awesome, but is way too "heavy".
If you want smooth animations, use CSS transition on the opacity property.
CSS render is handled by the gpu.